# Is it possible to implement REGEXP operator within the SQLITE shell?

Tags: regex, sqlite

SQLITE has a REGEXP operator but is not implemented. 
Is left out to the user to implement it with whichever programming language he is using.
I am queering databases from the sqlite shell.

Is it possible to add REGEXP support to SQLITE shell?

Comment: Yes, through extension loading.

Comment: Thanks @LS_dev. Can you be more specific? Can I do that without recompile the source? (I am using Windows, therefore I want to avoid that)

Comment: You don't have to recompile shell source, just use shell `.load` command. What you will need is to get an extension module which implements `REGEX`, or write your own.